# Issue in Android Layout - SoftKeyboard - Layout alignment

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-manifest, android-softkeyboard

Hello Am working on some layout design in Android.
Layout contains an EditText inside `Relativelayout` and `alignparentBottom='true'` is given to Relativelayout.

When Soft-keyboard opens, My Views remains same - this is okay.

But, The Relativelayout which is inside bottom in screen : which contains EditText is not coming upper side of my SoftKeyboard.

So far, I have done as below to solve but getting an issue explained above: (with `adjustPan`, my bottom layout is coming upperside of softkeyboard but, it also scrolls the whole screen upper.)

**In Manifeast** :

`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`

```
<activity
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:name=".MyActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="Camera Activity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

What might be the solution? 
thanks.

Comment: add ` android:layout_gravity="center"` to your `scrollview`. also make scrollview main parent.

Comment: ScrollView Main Parent ???

Comment: ScrollView for main view and put relative layout inside it.

Comment: its not working

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ScrollView` as parent view:

```
<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/login_form"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

and remember that `scrollview` accepts only one direct child, so wrap your whole layout inside it.
also use `linearLayout` insted of `relativeLayout`, something like this:

```
<ScrollView>
 <LinearLayout orientation="vertical">
   <LinearLayout orientation="vertical">
     <EditTexts />
   </LinearLayout>
   <Button />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: No success. Getting same result.

Comment: @VishalZaptech can you attach your layout?

Comment: @VishalZaptech also change `adjustResize` to `adjustPan` or `adjustNothing`

Comment: As I have explained that : (with adjustPan, my bottom layout is coming upperside of softkeyboard but, it also scrolls the whole screen upper.) in my question.

Comment: @VishalZaptech ok, then let me see your layout.

Comment: Added layout. please check question's EDIT part.

Comment: Try adding  android:fillViewport="true"  in your parent scrollview